# Enable the click event on checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on the 1st checkbox, then 2 checkbox is automatically checked and it can not be unchecked if 1st is checked and if 1 is not checked then 2 is checked manually and i am done this code in the javascript

```
if(firstCheckboxCheckd == true){
  secondCheckboxChecked.click = false;
}
else {
  secondCheckboxChecked.click = true;
}
```

Comment: and where is the question? what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that when 1st checkbox is unchecked and now i am trying to check the 2 checkbox its not working

Comment: I think we need to see more code in order to answer the question. Are you using a framework like React? Could you post the whole module containing this code, please?

Comment: if(isHeadquarter == 1){
  var headquarterRoleGroup = $(".<%=Constants.HEADQUARTER_BRANCH%>_"+roleGroupId);
  var isHeadquarterRoleGroupChecked = headquarterRoleGroup.is(":checked");
  $(".<%=Constants.NON_HEADQUARTER_BRANCH%>_"+roleGroupId).each(function(index, element){
   element.checked = isHeadquarterRoleGroupChecked;
   if(isHeadquarterRoleGroupChecked == true){
    element.click = false;
   } else {
    element.click = true;
   }
  });
 }

Comment: This looks like jQuery to me, which I've never used. Probably best to add a `jQuery` tag to get the attention of an expert. Also you should edit your original post to include that code. If you format the code nicely it'll be easier for people to read. However, I can tell you that a more concise way to write that big `if` statement is `element.click = !isHeadquarterRoleGroupChecked`. Also also... change your title to jQuery. This is not Java :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question right, but here is my take.

Requirement: - 
 When user check checkbox 1, it should automatically check checkbox 2

Issue : - 
When checking checkbox 1 and automatically checking checkbox 2, checkbox 2 doesnt response anymore

solution below

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#Checkbox1').click(function(){
        let firstCheckbox = $('#Checkbox1');
        let secondCheckbox = $('#Checkbox2');

        if(firstCheckbox.is(":checked"))
        {
        console.log('firstCheckbox is checked');
        secondCheckbox.prop('checked', true);
        secondCheckbox.prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else 
        {
        console.log('secondCheckbox is checked');
         secondCheckbox.prop('disabled', false);
        }

    })

});
```

Comment: No i want to remove the click event on checkbox 2 if checkbox 1 is checked
And if checkbox 1 is unchecked the again attach the click event on checkbox 2

Comment: Then why don't you just disable it after checking and enable it when checkbox 1 unchecked?  just updated the answer, see if that helps